# Find id from CSV using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I was given a .csv that contains two columns: `Name` and `description`. For each row within the `description` column, I am trying to find specific text. It looks like html or xml format and I was thinking about using the `Elemental Tree XML` library, but there are no indentations. Everything is a new line, so I felt that using `Regex` would be the simplest approach. Below is one of the rows. I put `#` in because I am not sure if the information is sensitive or not. About half way down there is a `td` tag that contains some letters and numbers (F00Y009). This is the information I am trying to grab and essentially put in another column. I haven't used the `Regex` library much and would appreciate some assistance.

This is what I have so far, but I don't quite understand how to say "search for text that starts with < td > contains capital letters and numbers and ends with with < /td > (disregard " " after <, stack wont let me do <> with something in-between).

```
import pandas
import re

col_list = ["Name", "description"]
df = pandas.read_csv(path to csv)
id = df["description"][0]
match = re.search("^<td>[A-Z0-9]</td>$", id)
print(match)
```

output:

```
[]
```

First row within "description" column:

```
<html ########>

<head>

<META ########>

<meta ########>

</head>

<body style="########">

<table style="########">

<tr style="########">

<td>########</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

<########>

<tr>

<td>########</td>

<td>########</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#########">

<td>########</td>

<td>########</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>########</td>

<td>########</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#########">

<td>########</td>

<td>F00Y009</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>SHAPE</td>

<td>Point</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="######">

<td>########</td>

<td>########</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>########</td>

<td>########</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#######">

<td>########</td>

<td>#######</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>########</td>

<td>{########}</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

desired output:

```
<td>F00Y009</td>
```

Comment: you can use beautifulsoup to extract information from html

Comment: You probably wanted `df[df["description"].str.match(r"<td>\w+</td>$")]`

Comment: This will do the job: `re.findall(r"<td>(\S+)</td>", open('filename.csv').read())`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That solution ends up giving me an empty dataframe.

Comment: @Hackaholic I have used beautifulsoup a long time ago. Though the file is not a html, so I am not sure it would work. I ended up using your solution with some modification since I have multiple rows that contain my example from above. So instead of using `open(filename.csv).read())` I put my `id` variable in. I'll just need to grab the index next!

Comment: @Hackaholic could you please post your answer and I'll accept it. Could you also explain what `(\S+)` is doing?

Comment: @Sabra But `<td>(\S+)</td>` matches `<td>########</td>`, do you really want it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is dummy data I think, OP want all data from <td>.......</td>

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is dummy data. I removed what was there because the information might be sensitive. You are correct I do not want it, but `\w+`  does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regex here

```
import re
re.findall(r"<td>(\S+)</td>", open('filename.csv').read())
```

() -> used for grouping and \S+ Matches any character which is not a whitespace character. This is the opposite of \s. If the ASCII flag is used this becomes the equivalent of [^ \t\n\r\f\v].

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you match and what you should not since the only example (currently) on the questions is the string `F00Y009` and that (as you will see below) matches a wide selection of things.  Also I don't actually think you want the `<td>` parts returned - just the ID.

Once your get your regex perfected try...

```
import pandas as pd
import re

pattern = r'<td>(\w+)</td>'

df = pd.read_csv(r'test_data.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')

def find_ids(row):
    ids = re.findall(pattern, row)
    return ids

df['ID'] = [find_ids(row) for row in df['Description']]

df.head()
```

Outputs:

```
    Name    Description ID
0   Janet   <html ########>\n\n<head>\n\n<META ########>\n...   [F00Y009, SHAPE, Point]
1   John    <html ########>\n\n<head>\n\n<META ########>\n...   [F00Y009, SHAPE, Point]
2   Burt    <html ########>\n\n<head>\n\n<META ########>\n...   [F00Y009, SHAPE, Point]
3   Bob <html ########>\n\n<head>\n\n<META ########>\n...   [F00Y009, SHAPE, Point]
```

I don't think you want 'SHAPE' and 'Point' so the regex probably needs tweaking but the code above should help.  Just swap the regex string assigned to the `pattern` variable if you change it.

Comment: This worked great as well for me, I'd upvote it, but don't have enough reputation do to so. And yes, the Shape and Point, I will need to remove.